# Avoid shadows when intersecting objects

Tags: shadows

I am trying to make a stone stair embeded in a concrete wall, but when I render the image, shadows appear at the intersection of objects.
I tried fiddling with Ambient occlusion but that won't change anything. Anyone have an idea about what is causing this?

Thank you :)

EDIT: render engine is cycles and i'm using blender 2.91

[image]

Comment: Well, they're normal shadows cast by the stairs. If you have light, you'll get shadows :))

Comment: I understand, but no there shouldn't be shadows like this unless there was a gap between the two objects.

Comment: This is Cycles or Eevee?  Please [edit] your post to include some more info and this will bump it to the front of active questions

Comment: If Eevee it's worth looking at the shadow settings and increasing Cube Size and Cascade Size values.

Comment: no unfortunatly it is in cycles. I am fairly new to blender so I am probably missing something